# Maximizing Window for Virtual Machine in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I installed VirtualBox 4.3.28 in Windows 8.1 and am running CentOS 7 within it.  But the problem is that VirtualBox is placing a size limit on the frame within which CentOS 7 is visible.  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, I maximized VirtualBox, but there is a lot of white space surrounding the CentOS 7 window.  I need to open lots of documents with small text in CentOS.

**How can I get rid of the white space so that CentOS 7 fills the entire space available in VirtualBox 4.3.28?**

Comment: Install virtualbox guest utils (search for it) and that should fix it. I know this has been asked somewhere else on stack exchange; a quick search should give you your fix. Link is here: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top...

- Download and install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) for your platform.
- Download and install the [VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
- Setup CentOS 7 in VirtualBox.

Become the root user with `su -` or `sudo -i`. Install software needed to compile the kernel module.

```
yum install -y kernel-devel gcc make
```

or (with more than you need but also a good method):

```
yum groupinstall -y 'Development Tools'
```

Update all software mostly to make sure that the kernel and its sources match:

```
yum update
reboot
```

With CentOS 7 running, choose *Devices* -> *Insert Guest Additions CD Image*.
Do not automatically run the script on the virtual optical device.
Become the root user with `su -` or `sudo -i`. And then mount the virtual optical device somewhere normal:

```
umount /dev/sr0
mount /dev/sr0 /mnt
```

Run the installer:

```
/mnt/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
reboot
```

There may be a superfluous `reboot` in here somewhere depending on the state of your software, but now you can enjoy the features of VirtualBox Extensions!

Comment: That did it!  Thank you and +1.  In my machine, the `Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image step` led to automatically running the VBoxLinuxAdditons... through the GUI.  And also, a preceding reboot got hung up for over half an hour so I had to just manually pull the power switch and reboot, breaking the update process.  But otherwise, your methods guided the solution and it works now.  No more shrunken image.  CentOS fills the screen.  Thank you.